# Filter streamed data in +page.svelte

Tags: sveltekit

I'm trying to create a filter for my streamed data in sveltekit.
The setup is, to load the first 10 post immeadiately, lazy load the rest/100 posts, and then replace the first loaded data with the lazy loaded data . The streaming works fine so far.
But the idea is to also to create a filter for the displayed posts. The initial filter in the each block works. But how can I afterwards filter the data/posts? Thanks in advance

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export function load() {
   return {
       posts: db.getBlogPostList(10), // first 10 posts
       lazy: {
           posts: db.getBlogPostList(100) // first 100 posts (slow)
       }
   };
}
```

```
<script>
    /** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
    import { Post } from '$lib';
    export let data;

    function filter(posts, bool) {
        return posts.filter((post) => {
            return post.verified == bool
        });
    }
</script>

{#await data.posts.lazy.posts}
    {#each data.posts.posts.items as post}
        <Post {post} />
    {/each}
    <p>Loading more posts...</p>
{:then posts}
    {#each filter(posts.items, true) as post}
        <Post {post} />
    {/each}
{:catch}
    <p>Error loading posts...</p>
{/await}

<button on:click={filter(???, false)}> Rerun Filter to false </button>
```